# Tab index for RadioButton list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to put a tab index for each item in the radio button list?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this is not recommended, as it deviates from standard user experience. So, only do it, when you really know what you are doing.

<strike>In the case when you know what you are doing, then just use standard HTML:</strike>

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" tabindex=2">Radio 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" tabindex=1">Radio 2<br>
```

Or in VisualStudio:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" TabIndex="2" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" TabIndex="1" runat="server" />
```

After re-reading your posting, here is some C# code, that does what you want, the VB code can be deduced quite easily:

On the frontend side:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>test</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 2;
    foreach (ListItem li in RadioButtonList1.Items)
    {       
        li.Attributes.Add("tabindex", counter.ToString());
        counter -=1;
    }
}
```