# Tab Index for ListItems in RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Is it possible to set Tab Index for ListItems in RadioButtonList. Here is my code:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radGender" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="M">Male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="F">Female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="U">Not Specified</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: take a look at this question and the only answer. It is not marked as answered, but maybe it works. [Tab index for RadioButton list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393931/tab-index-for-radiobutton-list)

Comment: duplicate--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393931/tab-index-for-radiobutton-list

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.Net Cannot tab through all radio buttons when selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103904/asp-net-cannot-tab-through-all-radio-buttons-when-selected)

Similar problem to yours. This should help with what you need as well as solve the problem you run into after having a radio buttom selected.

EDIT

Just to specify their solution. It seems after a choice is selected, using the arrow keys will let you move to the other choices where as tab will not. Another solution to getting around this is to have individual radio buttons and group them using the group name property.

Comment: There is a similar question in this website but that solution didn't resolve my issue. And in the link provided by Tony318, one of the solution suggest to create individual radio buttons and use the GroupName property to assign them all into one group. But i am using RadioButtonList through out my application already. So, if there if there is any simple solution to assign Tab Index for RadioButtonList would be great.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radGender" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="M" tabindex="1">Male</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="F" tabindex="2">Female</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="U" tabindex="3">Not Specified</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Seem to work at least in IE9 and FF (not sure with others).

Comment: I don't see any tabindex property for ListItem.

Comment: @ComputerGeek: `tabindex` is a html property. The RadioButtonList will be rendered as table and the ListItem as tablecell with a span(+ [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp)), input with type=radio and a label(f.e. `Male`). Since [tabindex works for span](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this should work too.

Comment: @ComputerGeek: What browser(s)?

Comment: @ComputerGeek: As i've mentioned in my answer i've tested it only with IE9 and FF, so this might be the problem.

Comment: I tried your code and tested it in FF. When i tab it through those ListItems for the first time its working fine and if i select one of them and come back and try to tab through those items its not working.

Comment: @ComputerGeek: It behaves exactly as in IE9, what does not work in your opinion?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11538/discussion-between-computergeek-and-tim-schmelter)